# is this possible to bookmark a page with html button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bookmarks

is this possible to bookmark a page with html button?

```
<button>Bookmark This page</button>
```

```js
function onclickfunction(){
  alert('Press Ctrl + D to bookmark this page');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="onclickfunction()">Bookmark this page</button>
```

this code instruct you to how to bookmark a page in chrome.
but i want to open a dialog box where we press finished in google chrome.

Comment: Now it is no longer possible for pages to add bookmarks on behalf of the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this script to bookmark your page, you can reference here [bookmark a url](https://web.archive.org/web/20171018001124/http://www.developersnippets.com/2009/05/10/simple-bookmark-script-using-jquery/)

[Original URL now redirects to a scam website that hijacks the browser's back button.
Original URL was: 
`http://www.developersnippets.com/2009/05/10/simple-bookmark-script-using-jquery/`]

```
$("button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the anchor tag from going the user off to the link
    var bookmarkUrl = "your_bookmark_url";
    var bookmarkTitle = "your_bookmark_title";

    if (window.sidebar) { // For Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
        window.sidebar.addPanel(bookmarkTitle, bookmarkUrl,"");
    } else if( window.external || document.all) { // For IE Favorite
        window.external.AddFavorite( bookmarkUrl, bookmarkTitle);
    } else { // for other browsers which does not support
         alert('Your browser does not support this bookmark action');
         return false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. i tried your answer and i got a error window.external.AddFavorite

Comment: console: `bookmark.html:31 Uncaught TypeError: window.external.AddFavorite is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (bookmark.html:31)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4435)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.js:4121)`

Comment: use this function on an anchor tag `<a>` click

Comment: `window.sidebar.addPanel` is no longer available since Firefox 23. `window.external.AddFavorite` is no longer available in IE.

Comment: No longer supported. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54763014/12675239

Answer (score 5):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#bookmarkme').click(function() {
    if (window.sidebar && window.sidebar.addPanel) { // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
      window.sidebar.addPanel(document.title, window.location.href, '');
    } else if (window.external && ('AddFavorite' in window.external)) { // IE Favorite
      window.external.AddFavorite(location.href, document.title);
    } else if (window.opera && window.print) { // Opera Hotlist
      this.title = document.title;
      return true;
    } else { // webkit - safari/chrome
      alert('Press ' + (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('mac') != -1 ? 'Command/Cmd' : 'CTRL') + ' + D to bookmark this page.');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="bookmarkme" href="#" rel="sidebar" title="bookmark this page">Bookmark This Page</a>
```

Comment: already done this but i want to open that dialog box which we get after pressing Ctrl + D.